# В Python при попытке загрузить библиотеку - ошибка "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement RPi"

Tags: python, pip, gpio, encoder

Мне нужна библиотека Encoder. И она даже есть среди установленных модулей. Однако когда импортирую `from Encoder.params_data import *` получаю ошибку:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'

Следом пытаюсь установить `RPi`, но получаю следующее уведомление:

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rpcio (c:\users\zlatt\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement RPi (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for RPi

Подумал, что `RPi` требует версии Python 3.8 (у меня сейчас 3.7.6, а pip версии 21.3.1), но установить не получилось - многочасовое тестирование конфликтующих зависимостей пришлось остановить. Хотя, возможно, версия Python здесь не при чем.

Следующая команда также не помогла - дает все тот же WARNING про -rpcio и ERROR про requirement RPi:

> pip install python3-rpi.gpio

То же предупреждение про игнорирование недопустимого -rpcio, если применить команду:

> pip install RPi.GPIO

При установке grpcio, вижу, что он имеется, хотя предупреждение про игнорирования -rpcio снова появляется.

Пока все попытки тщетны. Возможно, коллеги помогут с решением задачи?

Comment: Покапался тщательнее, обе библиотеки предназначены  для RaspberryPi. В документации указана OC как Linux. К тому же RPi работает с фактическими GPIO выводами, чего у вас не может быть на рабочей машине. Устанавливайте на RaspberryPi и тестируйте в том окружении

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо - я второй день прозанимался этим, хотя, судя по всему для стандартного компа с виндой это задача нерешаемая. Еще раз благодарю

Comment: Посмотрите ответ, я немного обманул Encoder. И  у меня запустился import. Но это костыли и вечный поиск багов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бибилиотеки предназначены для `RaspberryPi` и не предназначены для работы с локальной машины. НО можно обойти ваши ваши предупреждения и ошибки. Моя последовательность выглядела вот так. Установил на Win 10, Python 3.9.6.

1. Первое и важное: создал виртуальное пространство и активировал его

```
py -m venv env
env\Scripts\activate
```

2. Установка нужной нам Encoder

```
pip install Encoder
```

3. Проверим на что ругается

```py
import Encoder
"""
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
"""
```

4. Рядом с папкой `env` создал папку `RPi` и положил в него два файла `__init__.py` и `GPIO.py`. `GPIO.py`- пустой, а для `__init__.py` нашел содержание у любителей [здесь](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37780)

```py
#__init__.py
BOARD = 1
OUT = 1
IN = 1

def setmode(a):
   print (a)
def setup(a, b):
   print (a)
def output(a, b):
   print (a)
def cleanup():
   print ('a')
def setwarnings(flag):
   print (False)
```

5. Запускаем, проверяем

```py
>>> import Encoder 
>>> dir(Encoder) 
['Encoder', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'encoder']
```

Я не очень понимаю сценарий использования данной библиотеки, но сразу скажу что `Encoder` не содержит метода или поля `params_data`